# SelectedIndex getting lost when navigating ListView with DataPager

Tags: asp.net

I've added an `ListView` and a `DataPager` as usual. I rebind the data in the `DataPager_PreRender` event and I can navigate my data correctly. 
Yet, when I set the `ListView.SelectedIndex` in the `Listview_SelectedIndexChanging` event handler method, the "correct" selectedIndex gets lost when I navigate with the data pager.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah! I got the solution. I just need to add `EnablePersistedSelection="true"` to my `ListView`